# Trying to develop an IOS phonegap plug-in for Bluetooth Low Energy to send data between two iPhones

Tags: iphone, phonegap-plugins, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to develop a PhoneGap plugin for bluetooth low energy to send data between two iPhones, but I'm not very good with IOS.  I'm trying to use the Apple developer iOS sample released in November of last year, [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html), but I want to create my own user interface in HTML5/Javascript to interface with my application and just use this Apple sample to handle the data transfer and manage the Bluetooth framework coordination.  Any suggestions how to strip out the UI portion of the Apple sample code?

Comment: did you manage to implement the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the library called bluetoothme https://github.com/sergiomtzlosa/CoreBluetooth-Demo/tree/master/CBDemo
you'll only need bluetoothme.h and bluetoothme.m filesin that directory.

If you can replicate there connecting functions etc  in viewcontroller.m in your plugin then you'll be sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an active [project](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) in github implementing a bluetooth phone gap plugin (ble for ios and bluetooth classic for android).